# Qooxdoo: How to call MMock.verify() in an asynchronous test

Tags: unit-testing, asynchronous, qooxdoo

I'm trying to use `qx.dev.unit.MMock.verify()` in an asynchronous situation effectively the same as this:

```
, test_no_output_from_verify: function () {

   var mocker = this.mock({ callMeOnce: function () { } });

   mocker.expects('callMeOnce').once();

   qx.event.Timer.once(function () {
      mocker.verify();
      this.resume();
   }, this, 100);

   this.wait(1000);
}
```

I find that, when the `verify()` call throws an exception (because the `callMeOnce` function was not called), that exception is swallowed by the Test Runner. It carries on waiting for the 1000ms timeout to elapse, and then throws the standard timeout exception: '`Asynchronous Test Error: Timeout reached before resume() was called.`'.

Is there any way that I can make Test Runner halt immediately and display the exception thrown from `mocker.verify()` instead?

==============================

EDIT: Reading the manual one more time after posting the question shows my mistake. The correct technique is to put the verify() call inside the resume(), thus:

```
, test_no_output_from_verify: function () {
   var mocker = this.mock({ callMeOnce: function () { } });
   mocker.expects('callMeOnce').once();
   qx.event.Timer.once(function () {
      this.resume(function () {
         mocker.verify();
      });
   }, this, 100);
   this.wait(1000);
}
```

This works as expected and I get the `ExpectationError: Expected callMeOnce([...]) once (never called)` message inside the Test Runner.

Comment: When you solve your own problem, please, for the sake of the community, write an answer instead of just editing your question.